# Is it okay that the objective of a math thesis is to give a new proof of old theorem?

Tags: soft-question

In a math thesis, no matter it is in undergraduate or PhD, is it okay that the objective of a math thesis is to give a new proof of old theorem? Even though the new proof may be more complicated or lengthy than the original one. Is it valuable?

Comment: Sure! This happens all the time and it is extremely valuable, especially when it is done in a way that clarified what was originally essential. Forget theses, professional mathematicians write papers on this!

Comment: 'll expand on my comment. Excellent work often involves reproving old results, in a way that clarifies their point. I'm no historian, but here are two examples:

1. [Grothendieck's cohomological Proof of Zariski's Main Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zariski%27s_main_theorem) which was [conjectured by Serre](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/7764/b81a09dbd3d00338af87fce23b92e8c84260.pdf).

2. Serre's proof of rieman-roch was considered very important

Comment: You can find these all over the place. I guess the catch is you need a *Reason* to publish a new proof. I believe Erdos +Selberg famously gave the first elementary proofs of the prime number theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem

Comment: @AndresMejia Thanks !

Comment: No problem. In the future, I suspect the downvote may have been because this belongs somewhere in between this website and academia.SE. I can't read minds but perhaps recasting the question in terms of math would be better: how much mathematical content is there in proving old theorems? Is it worthwhile to revisit proofs of old theorems? etc. etc.

Comment: A proof by  a different method might be a way to find  additional knowledge..... Euler's analytic proof that there are infinitely many primes is longer and more complicated than Euclid's. But it gives extra info: That the sum of the reciprocals of the primes is infinite.

Comment: @AndresMejia. Erdos also published a new proof (when he was 18) of Bertrand's Postulate (first proved in 1857).

Answer (score 3):

**Warning**. My answer heavily relies on the comments to your question.

The critical point is to bring something new. If you give a new proof to an old theorem, this can happen either by improving the *statement* of the theorem or its *proof*. Let me consider these two cases separately.

**Improving the statement of the theorem**.

1. You use a weaker hypothesis. For instance, you generalise a theorem on complete metric spaces to complete uniform spaces, or a result valid for fields of characteristic $0$ without any characteristic assumption.
2. You prove a stronger result. For instance, you give a better upper [lower] bound. See for instance Timothy Gowers's upper bounds for [Van der Waerden's numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Waerden%27s_theorem). See also DanielWainfleet's comment about Euler's analytic proof that there are infinitely many primes, a very good example.

**Improving the proof of the theorem**.

1. You give a simpler proof with the same mathematical tools.
2. You give an elementary proof of a theorem involving difficult mathematics, even at the price of a lengthy proof. See Andres Mejia's example on Erdos-Selberg famous elementary proof of the prime number theorem.
3. You give a more sophisticated proof but it clarifies the argument (and often leads to a more general statement). See Andres Mejia's examples (Grothendieck's cohomological Proof of Zariski's main theorem and Serre's proof of Riemann-Roch theorem)
4. You give a proof within a weaker logical system. Typically, you manage not to use the axiom of choice, or you prove that a result still holds in a weak axiomatic system (logicians are fond of such results).

**EDIT**. As I was posting this answer, Hans Stricker asked whether [Fermat's last theorem is provable in Peano arithmetic?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2888541/is-fermats-last-theorem-provable-in-peano-arithmetic), a good example for (4).